# Java apply swaps in one array sort to another

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Say I have these two arrays:

```
int[] foo = new int[] {3, 4, 2, 1, 5};

int[] bar = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

If I sort `foo`, I want to apply the same swaps that were applied to it to `bar`.

So I would get this:

```
int[] new_foo = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int[] new_bar = new int[] {4, 3, 1, 2, 5};
```

How can I implement this easily, are there any reusable java methods so I don't have to go and implement this myself?

Comment: Try something before asking for a solution. That is the whole purpose of stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Never thought id have to say this. This is just an example. This isnt my real problem. I can't manually sort lists of size 500+. I need to be able to record the swaps and apply them to another array and I'm asking if there's an easy way I can do it in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers in array 1 and 2 belong together, you could create an object with the two belonging fields. Lets call that a "Pair" which has the properties "foo" and "bar". I would then create those pairs and sort them by their foo property like this:

```
public class SortPairs {

    static class Pair {
        final int foo;
        final int bar;

        Pair(int foo, int bar) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pair{" + "foo=" + foo + ", bar=" + bar + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Pair> pairs = Arrays.asList(
                new Pair(3, 1),
                new Pair(4, 2),
                new Pair(2, 3),
                new Pair(1, 4),
                new Pair(5, 5));

        System.out.println(pairs);

        Collections.sort(pairs, (pair1, pair2) -> pair1.foo - pair2.foo);
        System.out.println(pairs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you understand how to sort one array, then simply apply the "entry swap" to the second array when you swap cells in the first array.

Pseudocode (since this appears to be a homework problem):

```
sort code
if (need to swap cells i and j in Foo) {
  swap foo cell i with cell j
  swap bar cell i with cell j
}
loop end
```